# Can a Go module be published in the same path as the previous non-module module?

Tags: go, publish, go-modules

I have a small library that has always been hosted in a non-module repository but I now want to convert it to a Go module.

I successfully performed:

```
go mod init
go mod tidy
```

The `go.mod` and `go.sum` files were created with no errors and the library still passes testing.

The previous version was `v2.0.0`, so I incremented the version to `v3.0.0` and added `/v3` to the end of the module name in `go.mod`.  From what I have seen online, that is all that was necessary.
My `go.mod` files looks like this:

```
module tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3

go 1.19

require (
    github.com/lib/pq v1.10.9
    golang.org/x/text v0.9.0
)
```

I then published the library to our internal git server and thought I was ready to go.

When I attempted to add the library to a new Go module project, I received the following:

```
Installing: tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3
Installing dependency: tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3
go: module tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils@upgrade found (v2.0.0+incompatible), but does not contain package tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3
Failed to add dependencies: exit status 1
```

I found that if I published `v3.0.0` to a new path (`tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils2`), I was able to successfully add it to my new project, even if I again incremented the major version.

Am I missing something that would allow me to continue publishing in the same path, or is that just something you cannot do?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See [Go Modules: v2 and Beyond](https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules). I've not done this for any of my repos but I think you should create a subdirectory for v3 and copy that code there. Fundamentally, modules map to folder structures and the `/v3` appended to the module name expects the corresponding folder to exist. You may want to reconsider v2-->v3 unless your library includes breaking changes.

Comment: This solution has a solid foundation but it has been controversial. Even Google's been challenged by it with the [explanation for Protobuf API v1-->v2](https://go.dev/blog/protobuf-apiv2#versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported. And the version subdirectory is optional.

I found one case that will result in the error you saw. This happens when the main branch is not updated (still points to the tag `v2.0.0`) and the new tag `v3.0.0` is not pushed to the server. Please check carefully to make sure the remote repository has been updated.

If the remote repository has been updated but it still does not work, you can  narrow down the issue like this:

1. run `go get` with the `-x` option:

   ```
   $ go get -x tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3
   ```
2. `cd` into the directory shown in the output. The directory path is something like this:

   ```
   /home/username/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/96f42aa32430149c99ad6625ceafc5b59e047b9e11d6a03f687d59845b53b2d5
   ```
3. in this directory, run `git ls-remote -q origin` and check the output. The example below is the one on my machine when it does not work. You see that both `HEAD` and `v2.0.0` point to the same commit id, and there is not `v3.0.0`.

   ```
   $ git ls-remote -q origin
   5ac4c172806e80461086ea9feb485cec0b6a27f0    HEAD
   5ac4c172806e80461086ea9feb485cec0b6a27f0    refs/heads/main
   bbdc583c0b83489db1a30fa6ca8559ffa295a74d    refs/heads/other-branch
   5ac4c172806e80461086ea9feb485cec0b6a27f0    refs/tags/v2.0.0
   ```

Comment: When I run the first command, I get the following error at the end:
`go: tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3@v3.0.0: verifying module: tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3@v3.0.0: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3@v3.0.0: 404 Not Found    
        server response: not found: tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3@v3.0.0: unrecognized import path "tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3": https fetch: Get "https://tssgit.reyrey.com/teschste/go-utils/v3?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup tssgit.reyrey.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
`

Comment: When I run the second command I get the full list of versions, ending with:
`f51d56a56904520714ab34b708f79578bf9d0d3e        refs/tags/v2.0.0    
2ed7269f91055013f927b7e1eeddb7c68ef5fdb1        refs/tags/v2.0.0^{} 
d8ec6be2e36bf7cb8b0a4adb8d926c310299cf04        refs/tags/v3.0.0    
3e5c2421109764c6e8f97ad116dc0daa0014ab00        refs/tags/v3.0.0^{} `

Comment: OK, for some reason, it now works and I am able to add this library to another project.  I did not change anything I was doing, I am just glad it is now working.  Thanks!

Comment: @teschste Reply to the first comment: you should set `GOPRIVATE` with `go env -w GOPRIVATE="tssgit.reyrey.com"` (I thought you have already done that). See [Private modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-modules). Reply to the second comment: `refs/tags/v3.0.0^{}` looks weird. do you know where does it come from?

Comment: I do not have `GOPRIVATE` set but based on your comment, we will look into adding that.  Thanks!  
I do not know where `refs/tags/v3.0.0^{}` came from; I thought it looked strange as well.